# Getting state from MySql via PHP + JSON

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am building an android game in which I am attempting to download the user's profile from a MySql db into the local SQLite DB. I am able so the profile to the server but unable to retrieve it.

Here are the relevant android methods, there should be no issues with them they function properly although the logic itself may be off.

```
    //LOAD PROFILE CLASS
    userFunctions.getServerGameState(email, monster, qty, exp);
    db.saveLocalGameSate(monster, qty, exp);
    //FUNCTIONS CLASS
    public JSONObject getServerGameState(String email, String monster, int qty, int exp) {
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", get_game_state));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("monster", monster));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("qty", Integer.toString(qty)));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("exp", Integer.toString(exp)));

    // getting JSON Object
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(monsterURL, params);
    // return json
    return json;
}
    //DB HANDLER CLASS
    public void saveLocalGameSate(String monster, int qty, int exp){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_MONSTER, monster); // Do they own it
    values.put(KEY_QTY, qty); // Number of things they own
    values.put(KEY_EXP, exp); // monster's level

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(USERPROFILES_TABLE, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection

}
```

Here is the PHP, I believe my error lies in one of these two files.

index.php

```
 else if ($tag == 'get_game_state') {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $monster = $_GET['monster'];
    $qty = $_GET['qty'];
    $exp = $_GET['exp'];
    $result = $db->getGameState($email, $monster, $qty, $exp);
        if (!empty($result)) {

        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $response["error"] = 1;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Error getting game state from server";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

functions.php

```
public function getGameState($email, $monster, $qty, $exp) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT monster AND qty AND exp WHERE email = '$email'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $gamestate = array();
        $gamestate["monster"] = $result["monster"];
        $gamestate["qty"] = $result["qty"];
        $gamestate["exp"] = $result["exp"];

        // success
        $response["success"] = 1;

        // user node
        $response["GameState"] = array();

        array_push($response["GameState"], $gamestate);

        // echoing JSON response
        echo ($response);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

Here are some error messages I am receiving

```
06-12 14:15:52.046: E/JSON(10577): <b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in 

    <b>/home/content/40/8529140/html/webapps/monster/include/DB_Functions.php</b> on line <b>145</b><br />
06-12 14:15:52.046: E/JSON(10577): <b>Warning</b>:  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/home/content/40/8529140/html/webapps/monster/include/DB_Functions.php</b> on line <b>147</b><br />
06-12 14:15:52.046: E/JSON(10577): {"tag":"get_game_state","success":0,"error":1,"error_msg":"Error getting game state from server"}
06-12 14:15:52.046: E/JSON Parser(10577): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Lastly please don't tell me that my php insecure **I know this** PHP is not my strong point and I am looking to get a test version up and running. [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) is on my development roadmap and will be implemented.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**:

After fixing the SQL statement to select from the proper table

```
06-12 15:03:48.216: E/JSON Parser(11427): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Array of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: can you please share the "Request" structure that you expect at server side (PHP) ?

Comment: your mysql_query() is failing. Use mysql_error() to find out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$result = mysql_query("SELECT monster AND qty AND exp WHERE email = '$email'");

```
You missed table name . It should be as follows :

$result = mysql_query("SELECT monster,qty,exp from table_name WHERE email = '$email'")
```

Comment: thank you that was the reason the SQL statement was failing. Silly mistake. Please see my update at the bottom with the relevant error message now.

Comment: How did you parse your response of json ?

Comment: In the interest of not posting an entire class I am using the same class as [seen-here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) If you do control+F "JSON PARSER CLASS" I am using the exact class.

Comment: The error is in incorrect parsing. So please check parsing the response. JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user"); **user** is your json array name.